# c# load and unload form

Tags: c#, forms

how to load and unload form in C#.
so i have 2 form, login form and welcome form, so in here, i use session, if session is 1, when the login form load it's automatically closed and load welcome form.

I use this code,but it is not work,, the login form still open.

```
private void Login_Form_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string st = "1";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=GATEWAY-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=train_system;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employer WHERE session='" + st + "'",conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr1;
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr1.Read())
    {

        string dr = dr1[2].ToString();
        if (dr == "1")
        {
            Form1 fm = new Form1();
            fm.Show();
            Login_Form lf = new Login_Form();
            lf.Close();
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, your code looks like it's vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

```
if (dr1.Read())
{
    string dr = dr1[2].ToString();
    if (dr == "1")
    {
        this.Close();
        Form1 fm = new Form1();
        fm.Show();
    }
}
```

This line of code

```
Login_Form lf = new Login_Form();
lf.Close();
```

will create a completely new instance of the Login_Form and thus you are facing this problem

Comment: Yup!! Relevant code which ever you seems might be affecting show, close, hide of the forms.

Answer (score 0):

If the login form is your main form you can hide it with`this.hide();` in  the welcome form load event and then you can can create a closing event on your welcome form and there you can use `Application.Exit();` to shutdown everything in your application...

```
    if (dr1.Read())
{
    string dr = dr1[2].ToString();
    if (dr == "1")
    {
        Form1 fm = new Form1();
        fm.Show();
        this.hide();
    }
}

private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```